# writeToFile in Directory1/Directory2/ within the documents directory SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift and I've got a table view that displays files within programmatically created directories. I want to create a file within a directory that is within another directory.

> Example - Directory1/Directory2/fileIwantToCreate.pdf

I know how to access the documents directory but I'm not sure as to how I go about accessing a directory within a directory. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AMomchilov I've actually just figured it out. I simply have to append another directory to the string. Example - let Path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Path1/SubPath1/")

Comment: That's what I would have suspected. Please submit your answer to this question and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `writeToFile` in `DocumentDirectory`you need to have `NSData`of your pdf file, I'm assuming here that you have pdf file data.

For storing file in DocumentDirectory inside specific directory you need to check is directory is exist or not, if not create one.

```
var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
do {
    path = path.stringByAppendingFormat("/Dir1/Dir2")
    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    //Now write the data of pdf file here
    path = path.stringByAppendingFormat("/Filename.pdf")
    let data = NSData() //Here data is NSData of your pdf file
    try data.writeToFile(path, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to append another directory to the string.

> let Path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Path1/SubPath1/")